# Does Angular 2 and Ionic 2 generates Webview build for android?

Tags: android, angular, webview, ionic2

I am `Android` Developer. I just came to know that I can also create app using `Angular 2` and `Ionic 2`.
**Src:** https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-mobile-app-with-angular-2-and-ionic-2

I want to know that which option is better? Does It create `webview` when we create build in `Angular 2` and `Ionic 2` project?

Answer (score 2):

Ionic does not provide **NATIVE** application. Have a look at [NativeScript + Angular](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/introduction.html). NativeScript will convert web code to native application. Have fun!